# variable overwriting in PHP

Tags: php

For example I have this code:

```
$route = 'product/category';

//variable overload
$type  = explode('/',$route);
$type  = $type[1];
```

My thinking behind this is that I actually don't need unique variable name for exploded variable, so why not to overwrite?

Is this really bad concept? Or is there some more elegant way to write this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's absolutely not bad. All you're doing here is assigning a new value to a variable. It has no special name.

As for more elegantly writing it, you could write the following as of PHP 5.4: 
`$type = explode("/", $route)[0];`

Comment: Thanks, where can i find some documentation to your code?

Comment: It's mentioned in the documentation on array access [syntax](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing)

Comment: According to your link i have one off-topic question, so if I call php function, which returns array, i can specifically call array key which I want to get the same way as your code?

Comment: Yes, but only in PHP 5.4 and beyond.

Comment: From the PHP manual: "As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable." https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 2):

Other elegant solution:

```
list($type, ) = explode("/", $route);
```

I think it's the best one.